# Yeoman generator update

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to update my custom generator.

```
npm ERR! 404 'generator-blsp' is not in the npm registry.
```

The generator is working just fine, the old version.

I did some minor changes in the generator and changed the version number.

Then I ran the update generator function from the yo menu, I can still see the symlink to my project in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

Have I missed a step or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had 2 installations of node with the old generator installed in the other installation.

/usr/lib/node_modules

&&

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/